# WP7 - HLSL effects from WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I KNOW I did this in WP7 (not WP7.1) and I can't figure out what I did.

[I'm using this Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) 
[I'm using this Effect Build Task and Template](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962#DownloadId=40167)

So basically I opened my WP7 csproj file *in notepad* add added the following lines:

#### Under Project Root

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.PixelShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />

<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
    <PixelShaderCompile Sources="@(Effect)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </PixelShaderCompile>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>EffectCompile;$(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)</PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And System.Windows.Media.Effects does not contain

```
ShaderEffect
PixelShader
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or has a WP7 template for this that would be awesome. Thanks. I DO NOT was to use the XNA shaders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there has never been support of PixelShaders in WP7.

You must be mistaken with WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: Then, instead of voting down, show me where it says that WP7 supports pixelshaders.

Comment: WP7 is a reduced set of Silverlight. And I have done it before so I know its possible

Comment: Again: show me where it says that WP7 supports pixelshaders and then I'll help you search.

Comment: Again: Did you not read? It says it supports Silverlight....WP7 is a reduced set of Silverlight.

Comment: If WP7 is a reduced set of Silverlight (which I doubt) could it be they have taken out PixelShaders? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/1e7e7710-626d-4e32-9a7f-2fd203627ee7

Comment: From that thread: "To be clear, Windows Phone does not support custom pixel shaders in this release. The built-in DropShadow and Blur effects work, but you cannot write your own using HLSL."